# needed Trigger face effect and image-marker manually by JS

Tags: 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I need the face effects and image marker action to wait until the verification result is true then they can access them in order. Get verification from API -> open image marker -> found image -> trigger face effect

any help is very appreciated, I'm still new in this framework...

Answer (score 0):

8th Wall's AR Engine fires events/observables when various image and/or face events take place (image found, image lost, face found, face lost, etc). You can decide if/when you have a listener and can decide what action should take place when these events are fired.

For example, when a user clicks a button, that could register the face effects related event listeners.

More info on events:

https://www.8thwall.com/docs/web/#aframe-events

https://www.8thwall.com/docs/web/#image-target-events

https://www.8thwall.com/docs/web/#xr8xrcontrollerpipelinemodule

https://www.8thwall.com/docs/web/#xr8facecontrollerpipelinemodule